# Script runs in Pycharm but finished without an exit code

Tags: python, pycharm, exit-code

I've been running some simple python scripts in Pycharm as I develop an app.  The below described problem happens with every app within this project, while in other projects I'm not seeing this.

When I run the script, even if it's just a simple

```
print('Hello World.')
```

I do not get an exit code.  It looks as if I am running the program from the Python Console, but I'm running it by right clicking on the script and choosing run.

[image: screen shot still running]

I can rerun the script without issue, a new tab just opens in the python console window with an incremental (n) next to the filename.
What I end up doing is clicking on the red stop button which is when I do finally get the exit code.  I then close the tab and move on.

Answer (score 0):

In your "Run/Debug Configurations" choose "Emulate terminal ..."

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select emulate terminal in debug configs